# Apache rewrite rule for removing part of the directory from the url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, apache2

I have the following testing sites set up with apache and served from the following place `/htdocs/www/*`:

```
https://local.sweetcar.com/www/mycompany/
https://local.sweetcar.com/www/sweetcar/
```

I would like to configure an apache rewrite to serve the following urls

```
https://local.mycompany.com/
https://local.sweetcar.com/
```

So the **www/mycompany/** and the **www/sweetcar/** is removed from the url while everything else is preserved

This is what I tried with no success:

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
```

Comment: Does `local.mycompany.com` have a `VirtualHost` entry like `local.sweetcar.com` ?

Comment: Yea, both sites work using the above url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use these rules in site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !200
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^local\.([^.]+)\. [NC]
RewriteRule !^www/ www/%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I put the .htaccess in `/htdocs` and I'm getting a 500 error, any ideas?

Comment: Can you check your Apache error.log and see what the cause is

Comment: `Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.`

Comment: Getting the same 500 error and error to apache logs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210700/discussion-between-anchovylegend-and-anubhava).

Comment: This solution working if the url is exact, when attempting to go to a url like: local.mycompany.com/account/edit-account, I get a 404 and this error logged to apache '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/index.php' not found or unable to stat

Comment: Sorry it was way past midnight for me, just came online again. It appears you have more rules in your .htaccess. can you please provide your full .htaccess in question.